# Retaining changes made using Javascript to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page which is having 2 tabs.
On first tab i have a table which contains some 'n' rows.
Each row is having a text box and depending on value entered in that text box, values in other cells for that row are calculated using JavaScript.

Now the problem is whenever i am moving to second tab after updating the text boxes and again coming back to first tab, then the values which are calculated using JavaScript are not retained whereas values entered in text box are retained.

How to retain those calculated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either re-trigger the javascript that does these calculations in an onblur event handler, or store the calculated values in cookies/session.

Comment: Is there any thing i can do at DOM level to retain the changes w/o using cookies and other stuff.

Comment: If you re-generate large portions of the dom when switching tabs, you could try to store it externally. HTML5 has client side storage, but you might have to use a more compatible solution to account for other browsers (like older versions of IE). Maybe try creating a hidden input outside of the manipulated area, and caching the values there, reading them back once you switch tabs?

Comment: Ok, i will call that JS function again,

Comment: For cell values, calling JS function again solves the problem, but i have a functionality of user deleting the entire row. But here when user switches across tabs those deleted rows are getting displayed.How to solve this problem?

Comment: It could be solved the same way, but it would not be the best solution. How are you generating the tabs? The best would be not to regenerate everything on the tab - this would allow us to remove the hidden input hack, providing a more "clean" and mantainable solution :)

Comment: Those tabs are generated by AjaxControlToolkit:TabContaine and tables are generated by Listview in .NET. On second tab whatever user selected on first tab will be displayed. Whereas user can reconsider the selection on second tab by deleting them. Now the problem is after deleting, user visits the first tab those deleted rows are presenting on second tab.

Comment: Then you might have to mantain a server object containing the tab's criteria (requires a roundtrip), or use a trick similar to the hidden input (doesn't, but is "ugly"). I'd really go for cookies / javascript client variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could store this data in a cookie - this type of thing is exactly what they're for.

Comment: Is there any thing i can do at DOM level to retain the changes w/o using cookies and other stuff.

Comment: Sure, you could create one or more `hidden` inputs and store your data there - but if the page is reloaded, or the user visits another page, your 'stored' data would be gone. To retain information across many pages, cookies!